# Only allow access to files if logged in (htaccess?)

Tags: php, .htaccess

We have a set of files (images/documents) located on one subdomain (A), we then have another subdomain (B) that houses a CRM - both subdomains are hosted on the same server/IP and are subdomains of the same primary domain.

**What we're attempting to achieve** >
Only users logged into B can access files within A.

We've tried a few solutions with htaccess within A e.g. only allow access to A's files if they have the correct IP. We also tried writing htaccess to only allow access to A's files if the user has been referred from B's subdomain - however neither of the attempts have worked....it's notable that we're not thoroughly experienced with htaccess!

We're assuming it's an htaccess job, not sure if we can achieve the result by using PHP instead (preferable)?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that could be done with PHP, e.g. rewrite those requests to a special php file (using htaccess), in this file, do the normal checks and so on, and if the user got the right to see that file, display it to the user with e.g. `fpassthru` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php
Somethings, like wrong-header-sniffing, debug messages and so on needs to be adjusted, so the browser is able to display all file types correctly.

Comment: Thanks Michael - I've looked at fpassthru in the past, I was under the impression it can fail with larger file sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example, but needs more improvements:

On your CRM while starting the session, you need to make it available on all subdomains:

```
<?php

// Make session works on all subdomains
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
```

Then create an htaccess at the root of (A), with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /download.php?path=$1 [L]
```

This htaccess will make any request to any file on (A) gets processed by `download.php`.

And then create `download.php`, with the following contents:

```
<?php

if(! isset($_SESSION['your_session_id_here'])) {
    http_response_code(401);
    exit('Not allowed!');
}


if(! isset($_REQUEST['path'])) {
    http_response_code(400);
    exit('Invalid request!');
}

define('DOCUMENTS_ROOT', '/path/to/the/documents/');
define('AUTHORIZED_FILE_EXTENSIONS', ['png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'pdf', 'doc', 'zip']);

$path = DOCUMENTS_ROOT . $_REQUEST['path'];

$file_ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file_ext = strtolower($file_ext);
if(! in_array($file_ext, AUTHORIZED_FILE_EXTENSIONS)) {
    http_response_code(401);
    exit('Not allowed!');
}


// We already did this on Htaccess
//if(! file_exists($path)) {
//    http_response_code(404);
//    exit('Not found!');
//}

header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($path));
readfile($path);
```

Comment: Perfect - that's what I was hoping (a simple PHP solution)! All makes sense now, thanks Kerkouch

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: Kerkouch - that all seems to be working fine. I've got another question for you now. The method above works if you go to the php file and are authenticated, however, If we try and display the images on a webpage within our CRM how can we get that to work?

Comment: The solution I came up with was to authenticate the user via the PHP file, base64 encode the image and return it in JSON - seems to work well, I need to test this method when returning multiple files though to assess the loading time implications.

Comment: If this works fine and helped you, then you should upvote and accept this answer!